# Unity 2022.2.20 Collider2D often not working when object moving fast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use Unity 2022.2.20

I have this circle/ball using `Circle Collider 2D` and bunch of rectangle(maze) using `Box Collier 2D`, and obviously `Rigidbody 2D` for both.

[image: Circle/Ball] [image: Rectangle/Maze]

The issue is that when I rotate the maze fast, sometimes the ball doesn't collide with the maze. Video here:

> https://youtu.be/dzwvdDDqYWk

But if I rotate it slowly, the collider works well.

Is this known issue? are there any workaround for this issue?

Code that I use for rotation:

```
public float rotateSpeed = 100.0f;
private float playerInput;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    playerInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed * playerInput);

}
```

Also here is the `Time` setting in my Unity:

[image]

Update after for Tilemap:

Here is the MazeParent:
[image]

Here is the Tilemap (1 of 2 images):
[image]

Here is the Tilemap (2 of 2 images):
[image]

Comment: I think you should set the `Collision Detection` to `Continuous` on your `Rigid Body 2D`

Comment: i have tried it, it works better than `Discrete` but at some point the same issue happen. The downside (which I avoid) is that the ball movement will looks weird, it likes that the ball stick to the wall/maze.

Comment: Have you tried to tweek with [TimeStep](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html) in Unity?

Comment: You might be rotating the maze in a way that poorly interacts with the physics system.

Comment: Please show the code responsible for rotating.

Comment: added the code on the question. I use a simple `transform.rotate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you teleport the rigidbodies of the children of the GameObject "Maze" with `transform.Rotate()`. This means that Unity's Physics Engine has no information about what is happening on the way between position A and position B. Even setting the collision detection to "Continuous" is not sufficient here, especially at higher speeds.

What you need to do instead is to use the `MovePosition()` and `MoveRotation()` functions of the `Rigidbody` class. This allows the Physics Engine to collect all the necessary information itself during execution to continuously detect a collision. But even here there are limits due to numerical inaccuracies and possible limitations of the Physics Engine, so that above certain speeds collisions may not be detected. However, these velocities are well above what occurs in your use case. Furthermore, collisions are detected as part of the Fixed Update and are thus drawn much less frequently than frames. This is simply due to the costly calculations. As a consequence, your ball will penetrate the walls at high speeds, because the collision will only be detected after several frames have already been displayed in which the ball penetrates the wall. However, I don't recommend you to change the Fixed Timestep setting, because it will have a negative impact on the performance, especially since you are already using continuous collision detection.

I have recreated your case and written the following class for the rotation, from which you can take the implementation of the things mentioned above. The thing that makes it a bit more complicated in your case is that you have to manipulate each rigidbody individually and determine its position and rotation.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotateSpeed = 100.0f;
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public float playerInput = 0;

    List<Rigidbody2D> rbList;

    void Start()
    {
        var childCount = transform.childCount;
        rbList = new List<Rigidbody2D>();
        for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < childCount; childIndex++)
            rbList.Add(transform.GetChild(childIndex).GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>());
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var rotationAngle = Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed * playerInput;
        var rotationDelta = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * rotationAngle);

        rbList.ForEach(rb =>
        {
            var relativePosition = rb.position - (Vector2)transform.position;
            var rotatedRelativePosition = rotationDelta * relativePosition;
            var newPosition = transform.position + rotatedRelativePosition;

            rb.MovePosition(newPosition);
            rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation + rotationAngle);
        });
    }
}
```

Also, it is important that you set the `Body Type` of your maze's rigidbodies to `Kinematic` in order to use the two methods above. Furthermore, you can set the `Collision Detection` to `Discrete` for the rigidbodies of the maze as long as it is set to `Continuous` for the rigidbody of the ball. Thus you avoid some unnecessary and computationally expensive calculations.

Besides that I also made the playerInput as a slider so you have more control in the editor when testing. I was able to go up to a value of about 32 before the ball said goodbye, but that should do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but MoveRotation() can't be use on Static object. The maze(the one that rotates) are Static object, it only rotate not moving at all.

Comment: I just realized that `Kinematic` can also be "static" meaning it only rotate not affected by force of other object. This solution is working well :) https://youtu.be/_0FLRhM3zR0

Comment: I am back again. The code works well, but when I use it on Tilemap the issue happened again. https://youtu.be/fO967SY2h8Q any idea how to tweak it? I have been trying to tweak the timer, update function, etc. Nothing works

Comment: Could you please show the MazeParent's inspector and its children once so I can see how you configured the tilemap collider and so on.

Comment: Added on the initial question

Comment: another note: when the ball hit the maze while the maze rotates, the maze jitters.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to rebuild the whole thing right now (maybe you can provide the relevant part in a repository), but you can already try to use the CompositeCollider2D component. This is a bit more expensive again, but could solve both the original problem and the jittering. But this is just a guess, because as I said I can't test it right now.

Comment: here is the sources: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OBza5s3PmWTwMujwYwdR9vCn5yNU8ieZ/view?usp=sharing , i haven't been able to upload it VC. For the jitter i have tried to: use composite collider and get the user input on Update and rotate the maze on FixedUpdate. Nothing works :(